# Hibernate lazy load and eager load

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

What is the difference between Lazy-Load="false" and eager loading ,  I am not getting the proper anywere , please let it me know

Answer (score 0):

"Eager fetching" is the same as not lazy-loading, though I think what you're asking is the difference between specifying eager fetching in a query vs mapping an association as non-lazy. The former is to be strongly preferred over the latter. Lazy relationships are covered extensively under ["Fetching strategies"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) in the reference guide.

Comment: so both are same lazy-fetching=false(not-lazy loading) and eager fetching according to the above comments

Answer (score 0):

A very clear explanation about the difference between lazy loading and eager fetching is explained [here](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/).